# singleemailmessage and activity

Tags: apex, visualforce, singleemailmessage

I have a controller that I am using to create an email from a template.  The template pulls a custom object and sends an email to several people via to:, cc:, and bcc:.  I added the settargetobjectid command and commented out the to: email address set and now I get the activity on the contact.  I would also like to have the activity recorded on the custom object.  When I do it manually and select the related to object, the activity is recorded both places.  How can I get it to do the same in my code?

```
public class AffEngpdfExtension 
{
public ID callersId;
private String transferUrl;

public String recipientEmail { get; set; }
public String ccEmail { get; set; }
public String bccEmail { get; set; }
public String subjectEmail { get; set; }
public String bodyEmail { get; set; }
public String templateBody { get; set; }
public String docName { get; set; }
public String TransferPage { get; set; }
public String targetObjectId { get; set; }

// Constructor
public AffEngpdfExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    stdController.addFields(new List<String>{ 'Name', 'User_Email__c', 'Oversight_Email__c', 'Sales_Rep_Email__c',
        'User_Contact__c' });
    Affiliate_Consulting_Engagement__c affEngage;
    affEngage = (Affiliate_Consulting_Engagement__c)stdController.getRecord();

    callersId = stdController.getRecord().id;
    //this.recipientEmail = affEngage.User_Email__c;
    targetObjectId = affEngage.User_Contact__c;
    ccEmail = affEngage.Oversight_Email__c + ';' + affEngage.Sales_Rep_Email__c;
    List<Contact> senderEmail = [SELECT Id, Email FROM Contact WHERE pse__Salesforce_User__c=:UserInfo.getUserId() LIMIT 1];
    bccEmail = senderEmail[0].Email;
    EmailTemplate templateId = [select HTMLValue from EmailTemplate where developerName = 'AffEngEmail'];
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(templateId.Id, null, callersId);
    bodyEmail = email.getHTMLBody();
    bodyEmail = bodyEmail.replaceall('<p style="', '<p style="margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px;');
    bodyEmail = bodyEmail.replaceall('<p>', '<p style="margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px;>');
    templateBody = bodyEmail;
    subjectEmail = email.getSubject();
    docName = affEngage.Name + '-' + affEngage.Engagement_Code__c;
}

// Email content...

public PageReference emailPdf() {

    if(String.isBlank(this.TransferPage)) {
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 
           'Internal Error: missing TransferPage in pdfExtension'));
        return null; // early out
    }

    if(String.isBlank(this.recipientEmail)) {
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 
           'You must enter a Send To email address !'));
        return null; // early out
    }

    if(String.isBlank(this.subjectEmail)) {
        subjectEmail = docName;
    }

    String tempstr = this.bodyEmail;
    tempstr = tempstr.replaceall('[^\\W\\D]*','');
    if (String.isBlank(tempstr)) {
        bodyEmail = 'Document(s) attached for your review.';
    }

    transferUrl = '/apex/' + TransferPage + '?scontrolCaching=1&id=' + callersId;
    PageReference pdfPage = new PageReference(transferUrl);
    Blob reportPdf;
    try {
        reportPdf = pdfPage.getContentAsPDF();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        reportPdf = Blob.valueOf(e.getMessage());
    }

    // Create email
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    List<String> addresses = new List<String>();
    addresses.clear(); 

    message.setTargetObjectId(targetObjectId);

    if (!String.isBlank(this.recipientEmail)) {
        addresses = this.recipientEmail.split(';');
        message.setToAddresses(addresses);
    } else
    addresses.clear();

    if (!String.isBlank(this.ccEmail)) {
        addresses = this.ccEmail.split(';');
        message.setCcAddresses(addresses);
    } else
    addresses.clear();

    if (!String.isBlank(this.bccEmail)) {
        addresses = this.bccEmail.split(';');
        message.setBccAddresses(addresses);
    } else
    addresses.clear();

    message.setSubject(subjectEmail);
    message.setHtmlBody(bodyEmail);

    // Attach PDF to email and send
    Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachment = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
    attachment.setContentType('application/pdf');
    attachment.setFileName(TransferPage + '_' + docName + '.pdf'); 
    attachment.setInline(false);
    attachment.setBody(reportPdf);
    message.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[]{ attachment });
    message.setSaveAsActivity(true);
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{ message });
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO,
       'Email with PDF attachment sent to ' + this.recipientEmail + ' ' +
                                              this.ccEmail + ' ' +
                                              this.bccEmail));
    return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use SingleEmailMessage's setWhatId to specify a standard or custom object that has activities enabled in addition to setTargetObjectId to specify the user or contact to email. You can read more about it [in the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm).

Comment: Thanks!  That works perfectly.  The client just asked me if it is possible to add an activity to another custom object to show the email was sent, so basically can I set multiple whatids to add the activity to the contact and 2 different custom objects?  Do I have to write code in the controller to manually add the additional activity?

Comment: @JerryWelliver Yes, you can only attach one custom/standard object plus one contact, so if you need more, you need to duplicate the activities.